# String consisting of multiple sub-strings?

Tags: vb.net, string, split, epplus

I am using EPPLUS to retrieve string values from Excel. The strings take the form:
"117
60%
A"
and I split them at the linebreaks. This worked perfectly normal when I used Interop to retrieve the values. But I switched to EPPLUS because Interop is rather slow.
But suddenly the Parse method fails because the 60% does contain some additional ...strings. They look and print normal, but the Visual Sutdio editor shows me that the string takes the form: ' "60%" & vbCr & "" '. What is the meaning of the "&". Normally it would show a string concenation, but that makes not too much sense.
Does anyone have an Idea about how to detect this problem?

Code:

```
dim TestString="117
60%
A"

Dim Splitstring() As String = Split(Value, Chr(10))

for i=0 to splitstring.length-1
    debug.print(Splitstring(i))
next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you split only with chr(10) = LF while the CR (chr(13)) remains in your string. Windows uses CRLF (13,10) as a line terminator - a relic from the days of the terminals.

try:

```
dim TestString as string = "117
60%
A"

Dim Splitstring() As String = Split(TestString.Replace(vbCr,""), vbLf)

for i=0 to splitstring.length-1
    debug.print(Splitstring(i))
next
```

This way it doesn't matter if there is a CR or not (ie. Linux text files) that are being parsed. Hope this helps.